# jsPDF - HTML to PDF is not showing SVG (chart)

Tags: charts, plotly, jspdf, html-to-pdf

While converting whole HTML body to PDF, SVG showing blank area. Actually I am exporting **Plotly charts** to PDF.

I think SVG is not supported in **jsPDF**. But looking for the suggestions.

Here is the code that i used:-

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

doc.addHTML(document.body, function () {
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');        
});
```

Comment: use `html2canvas` to convert the page to an image, then send the image to pdf...